# Using "readlines()" twice in a row

Tags: python, io, readlines

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Lines = file.readlines()
# do something
Lines = file.readlines()
```

but the second time `Lines` is empty. Is that normal?

Answer (score 13):

You need to reset the file pointer using

```
file.seek(0)
```

before using

```
file.readlines()
```

again.

Comment: Or else store a copy of the lines.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, because `.readlines()` advances the file pointer to the end of the file.

Why not just store a copy of the lines in a variable?

```
file_lines = file.readlines()
Lines = list(file_lines)
# do something that modifies Lines
Lines = list(file_lines)
```

It'd be far more efficient than hitting the disk twice. (Note that the `list()` call is necessary to create a copy of the list so that modifications to `Lines` won't affect `file_lines`.)

Comment: Your technique here sets `Lines` to the same Python object as `file_lines`.  Anything that mutates one would mutate the other for they are the same object.  To really be safe, you need to do `lines = file_lines[:]` or in some other way make an actual copy.  By the way, the PEP 8 standard suggests using lower-case for variable names, and reserving mixed-case for classes, so I suggest changing `Lines` to just `lines`.

Comment: @steveha - I already added `list()` calls. As for the variable name, I was simply re-using the OP's name to make it easier for them to read. I agree with you that lower-case is generally better.

Comment: My apologies.  I'm not sure how I missed the `list()` wrapper but I did.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to not have to reset every time by using seek method again and again, use the readlines method, but you must store it in variable like this example below:

```
%%writefile test.txt
this is a test file!
#open it
op_file = open('test.txt')
#read the file
re_file = op_file.readlines()
re_file
#output
['this is a test file!']
# the output still the same
re_file
['this is a test file!']
```