# How to split line in readlines and save them in different list?

Tags: python, split, nlp, tokenize, readlines

this is my code

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as source:
    # Indentation
    polTerm = [line.strip().split()[0] for line in source.readlines()]
    polFreq = [int(line.strip().split()[1]) for line in source.readlines()]
```

this is inside file.txt

```
anak 1
aset 3
atas 1
bangun 1
bank 9
benar 1
bentuk 1
```

I got the polTerm just like what I want:

> ['anak', 'aset', 'atas', 'bangun', 'bank', 'benar', 'bentuk']

but for the polFreq, instead of this:

> ['1', '3', '1', '1', '9', '1', '1']

what I got is blank list like this:

> [ ]

anyone know why this happened? and how to fix this so I can get just like I what I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using "readlines()" twice in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201008/using-readlines-twice-in-a-row)

Comment: thanks for your answer! another question, is there a better way to do it beside this?

Comment: thanks!, i just add `lines = source.readlines()` before `polTerm = [line.strip().split()[0] for line in source.readlines()]` and change all `source.readlines` to `lines`

Comment: You have 4 answers, which seem solve your issue.
 
You still need help or advice on some details on these answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Carcigenicate said, `.readlines` is a generator that returns a list. If you don't save that list in a variable, calling a generator a second time will return nothing, because the generator has been exhausted in your first call. What you want is this:

```py
with open("file.txt","r") as inf:
    # Now your lines list is saved in a global variable 
    # which can be used outside with open().
    # The .readlines generator is exhausted and won't return 
    # anything.
    raw = inf.readlines()

polTerm = [line.strip().split()[0] for line in raw]
polFreq = [int(line.strip().split()[1]) for line in raw]
```

Pro tip: Learn to use pandas, specifically, pd.read_csv().

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as source:
    lines = source.readlines()
    polTerm = [line.strip().split()[0] for line in lines]
    polFreq = [int(line.strip().split()[1]) for line in lines]
```

The reason is that `readlines()` is an iterator, so the first call has already consumed it and it becomes empty and when you try to use that empty iterator the second time you find it empty.

Comment: You could unindent the last two lines. They don't have to be in the `with` statement.
This would close the file a little earlier

Comment: @gelonida i know. But that's another question, an efficiency question. If you answer two questions at the same time it could be a plus of complexity for the asker. I just barely modified his code so that he can follow along and figure out where he was getting mistaken.

Comment: True. I just thinks it's easier to read and makes it clearer that the file access is done (that the file is only read once).
But of course in this case it's not really important.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.txt','r') as source:
     data=source.readlines()
a1=[] 
a2=[] 
for line in data:
     x=line.split()
     a1.append(x[0])
     a2.append(x[1])
```

Comment: You could unindent immediately after the `data=` line.
This would close the file a little earlier and reduce the indentation level (In my opinion normally a good idea)

Comment: That is true, thanks for the advice, it's very useful regarding efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

@Carcgenicate gives you the literal answer.

However in my opinion you just shouldn't read the file twice (Except the file is really huge and all of its lines wouldn't fit into memory.

If the files are not that huge there is no need to read in a file twice.
If it is a little huge, then just read the first two columns into memory.
and separate them afterwards.

What I'd suggest is:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as source:
    cols_1_and_2 = [line.strip().split(None, 2)[:2] for line in source.readlines()]

polTerm = [cols[0] for cols in cols_1_and_2]
polFreq = [int(cols[1]) for cols in cols_1_and_2]
del cols_1_and_2  # this line is to free some memory if that would be an issue
```