# How to implement for loop while opening text file

Tags: python

I am trying to get each value from data.txt into my list. Unfortunately, I do not understand why For Loop does not work in the following case:

#(data length is 8)

```
example_list = []

with open("/path/data.txt") as example:

    for number in range(example.readlines())):
        example_list.append(example.readlines()[number])

print(example_list)
```

Error *list index out of range* appears.

When in stead of For Loop I manually insert "number" (from 0 to 8) it does work, therefore I do not understand why it does not work with for loop

Appreciate any help on that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using "readlines()" twice in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201008/using-readlines-twice-in-a-row)

Comment: `example.readlines()` already gives you a list of the lines, you don't need to loop over and create a new list. You can just do `example_list = example.readlines()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to iterate over the contents of a file, you first
have to check what file structure the method you use returns. In this case,
`readlines()` returns a list. [Link](https://www.edureka.co/blog/python-readline/#readlinesexample).

You can not use a list as an argument for `range()` because it expects an integer.

So you need to iterate over that list returned by `readlines()`, not over the file itself.

```
example_list = []

with open("file.txt") as example:
    # lines is a list
    lines = example.readlines()
    for item in lines:
        # add each element to the example_list
        example_list.append(item)

print("example list: ", example_list)
```

You can also use `example_list.append(item.strip())` to get cleaner data. [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp)

Comment: Note that over a file-like object does already iterate over lines. The `.readlines()` method simply collects all lines into a list. See e.g. [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase): "`IOBase` (and its subclasses) supports the iterator protocol, meaning that an `IOBase` object can be iterated over yielding the lines in a stream. Lines are defined slightly differently depending on whether the stream is a binary stream (yielding bytes), or a text stream (yielding character strings). See `readline()` below."

Comment: I offer that the problem is more that OP fundamentally misunderstands loops in Python, moreso than their lack of reading the docs for `.readline()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over file's lines like this:

```py
example_list = []

with open("/path/data.txt") as example:
    for number in example:
        example_list.append(number)

print(example_list)
```

Or simplier

```py
example_list = open("/path/data.txt").readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
example_list = []

with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        example_list.append(line.strip())

print(example_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest (and imho best) version:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    example_list = [line.strip() for line in f]
```